# Binding different controls c#

Tags: c#, data-binding, expression

In my application, Say I have 3 Numeric controls. If the user change value of Control1, then it should affect the Control 2 & Control 3 based on the below expression.

Control 2 = Control 1 * 3
Control 3 = Control 1 * 5 + 4

Please suggest your ideas.

Thanks

Comment: Which UI technology? Wpf, winforms or what? and what you have tried?

Comment: You could define a container type and bind the controls to three separate properties all sharing the same backing field (which is what Control1 is bound to) and for Controls 2 and 3's properties, implement the math in the getters.  Don't forget to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I am using WPF. and I tried [Multiple Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). But the problem is I have to manually parse the expresssion. Is there a way to automatically evaluate and update?

Answer (score 0):

In the case of textbox control

```
int a=Convert.ToInt(textbox1.text); 
textbox2.text = Convert.ToString(a * 3);
textbox3.text = Convert.ToString(a* 5 + 4);
```

Comment: I have these expressions from some file and it is not static. And I will know the relation between controls during runtime.